# redirecttopage with area and parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to redirect to another page with using public variables, but somehow I don't get the area properly in there

This is working

```
return RedirectToPage("/Facility/IbuEdit", new { area = "Setup", IbuId });
```

but I'd like to use it this way

```
return RedirectToPage("/Facility/IbuEdit.cshtml",("here the area is needed", Setup.Pages.Facility.IbuEditModel.IbuId = IbuId));
```

I tried already

```
return RedirectToPage("/Facility/IbuEdit",(new {area = "Setup"}, Setup.Pages.Facility.IbuEditModel.IbuId = IbuId));
```

there's no error coming, but not working either...

Comment: `RedirectToPage("/Facility/IbuEdit.cshtml",(new {area = "Setup"}` it would generate URL to the **Pages/Facility/IbuEdit.cshtml.cshtml** page in **Setup** area, are you sure there is a file named **IbuEdit.cshtml.cshtml**? Please clarify the actual scenario that require doing this.

Comment: As I wrote is the link in the first version working. Good that you doubting something, that wasn't the question and problem.
The scenario doesn't require this, I just would like to know whether it's possible and if, how.